# Что такое Task.Yield()?

Tags: c#, tpl

Я не понимаю что это, как работает и в каких случаях используется. Может кто-нибудь по-русски объяснить?

Comment: Как я понял возвращает в контекст синхронизации, который был на начало async метода. Например если метод начался в UI потоке и потом ушел в другой поток на каком то await, то Task.Yield() вернет в UI поток

Comment: @vitidev вы ошибаетесь

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Этот метод возвращает специальное значение, предназначенное для передачи оператору `await`, и в отрыве от этого оператора не имеющее смысла.

Конструкция же `await Task.Yield()` делает довольно простую вещь — прерывает текущий метод и сразу же планирует его продолжение в текущем контексте синхронизации.

Используется же эта конструкция для разных целей.

**Во-первых**, эта конструкция может быть использована для немедленного возврата управления вызывающему коду. Например, при вызове из обработчика события событие будет считаться обработанным:

```
protected override async void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    await Task.Yield(); 
    // (какая-то логика)
}
```

**Во-вторых**, эта конструкция используется для очистки синхронного контекста вызова. Например, так можно "закрыть" текущую транзакцию (ambient transaction):

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope()) {
  // ...
  Foo();
  // ...
  ts.Complete();
}

async void Foo() {
  // ... тут мы находимся в контексте транзакции
  if (Transaction.Current != null) await Task.Yield();
  // ... а тут его уже нет!
}
```

**В-третьих**, эта конструкция может очистить стек вызовов. Это может быть полезным, если программа падает с переполнением стека при обработке кучи вложенных продолжений.

Например, рассмотрим упрощенную реализацию `AsyncLock`:

```
class AsyncLock
{
    private Task unlockedTask = Task.CompletedTask;

    public async Task<Action> Lock()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        await Interlocked.Exchange(ref unlockedTask, tcs.Task);

        return () => tcs.SetResult(null);
    }
}
```

Здесь поступающие запросы на получение блокировки выстраиваются в неявную очередь на продолжениях. Казалось бы, что может пойти не так?

```
private static async Task Foo()
{
    var _lock = new AsyncLock();
    var unlock = await _lock.Lock();

    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) Bar(_lock);

    unlock();
}

private static async void Bar(AsyncLock _lock)
{
    var unlock = await _lock.Lock();
    // do something sync
    unlock();
}
```

Здесь продолжение метода `Bar` вызывается в тот момент, когда другой метод `Bar` выполняет вызов `unlock()`. Получается косвенная рекурсия между методом `Bar` и делегатом `unlock`, которая быстро сжирает стек и ведет к его переполнению.

Добавление же вызова `Task.Yield()` перенесет исполнение в "чистый" фрейм стека, и ошибка исчезнет:

```
class AsyncLock
{
    private Task unlockedTask = Task.CompletedTask;

    public async Task<Action> Lock()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        var prevTask = Interlocked.Exchange(ref unlockedTask, tcs.Task);

        if (!prevTask.IsCompleted) 
        {
          await prevTask;
          await Task.Yield();
        }

        return () => tcs.SetResult(null);
    }
}
```

Кстати, альтернативный способ починить код выше — использование флага `RunContinuationsAsynchronously`:

```
class AsyncLock
{
    private Task unlockedTask = Task.CompletedTask;

    public async Task<Action> Lock()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);

        await Interlocked.Exchange(ref unlockedTask, tcs.Task);

        return () => tcs.SetResult(null);
    }
}
```

**В-четвертых**, при использовании в UI-потоке эта конструкция позволяет обработать накопившиеся события ввода-вывода, что полезно при длительных обновлениях интерфейса.

Например, при добавлении миллиона строк в таблицу программа не будет реагировать на действия пользователя, пока все строки не будут добавлены. Но если, к примеру, после добавления каждой тысячи строк вставлять вызов `await Task.Yield()` - программа сможет обрабатывать действия пользователя и не будет выглядеть зависшей.

В *WinForms* для тех же целей можно было использовать метод `Application.DoEvents()` - но его избыточное использование приводило к переполнению стека. `await Task.Yield()` - это универсальный способ, который можно использовать как в *WinForms*, так и в *WPF*.

Comment: Спасибо. Я проверю все эти вещи позже. Возможно появятся вопросы. Пока вроде все ясно.

Comment: 1) в первом случае есть разница между `await Task.CompletedTask` и `await Task.Yield()`? 2) можно подробнее про очистку синхронного контекста вызова? первый раз слышу это словосочетание 3)как это может очистить стек вызовов, если Yield делает тоже самое, что и остальные асинхронные функции (планируют продолжение)? можно на примере? 4) строки добавляются пачкой (за один асинхронный вызов) или каждая по-отдельности?

Comment: @Qutrix Разница между CompletedTask и Yield конечно же есть! `await Task.CompletedTask` не делает *вообще* ничего, это пустая операция.

Comment: Я конкретно про первый случай: "эта конструкция может быть использована для немедленного возврата управления вызывающему коду". await Task.CompletedTask тоже сразу возвратит управление же, не?

Comment: @Qutrix `await Task.CompletedTask` не вернет управление вызывающему коду: https://ideone.com/NCUfEu

Comment: Ах, да, понял. А можно еще тогда ответ на 2 и 3?

Comment: @PavelMayorov А await Task.Wait не тоже самое? А во втором случае, если мы вышли из контекста, то мы можем в него как-то вернуться?

Comment: @iluxa1810 не знаю такого метода. Точнее, знаю - но он не статический и не может использоваться вместе с await.

Comment: @PavelMayorov точнее Task.Delay

Comment: @iluxa1810 метод Task.Delay ждет указанное время. Метод Task.Yield ничего не ждет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а если 0 передать?

Comment: @iluxa1810 а если 0 передать - это будет то же самое что и Task.CompletedTask

Answer (score 10):

Я думаю, что здесь никто не ответил на вопрос, зачем нужна Task.Yield.
Она нужна когда задача (Task) использует бесконечный цикл (вообще любая продолжительная, синхронная работа) и может удерживать поток из пула только для себя и не давать другим задачам использовать этот поток. Task.Yield переотправляет задачу в очередь пула потоков и другие задачи, которые ожидали выполнения смогут использовать данный удерживаемый поток.

Пример:

```
  CancellationTokenSource cts;
  void Start()
  {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        // Запускаем асинхронную операцию
        var task = Task.Run(() => SomeWork(cts.Token), cts.Token);
        //  Ждем окончания
        // После окончания операции обрабатываем результат/отмену/исключения
    }

    async Task<int> SomeWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        int result = 0;

        bool loopAgain = true;
        while (loopAgain)
        {
            // Что-то делаем ...

            loopAgain = /* проверка на окончание цикла && */  cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested;
            if (loopAgain) {
                // переотправляет задачу в очередь пула потоков чтобы другие задачи, которые ожидали выполнения смогли использовать данный поток
                await Task.Yield();
            }
        }
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return result;
    }

    void Cancel()
    {
        // Запрашиваем отмену операции
        cts.Cancel();
    }
```

Comment: Верно, именно так. Лучше и проще для понимания [объяснено](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html) ([и ещё](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html))  в мануалах к потокам на С, смысл работы yield одинаковый, рекомендую прочитать.

Comment: @NewView функции pthread_yield и sched_yield делают совершенно другое и нужны для других целей

Comment: @MaximT у вас какой-то очень странный пример: вместо Task.Yield тут было бы тут было бы проще ConfigureAwait убрать, эффект был бы тот же самый кроме последней итерации цикла. Этот цикл что, в среднем одну итерацию выполняется раз его пришлось так оптимизировать?

Comment: @MaximT кроме того, тут очень странно используется Interlocked.CompareExchange...

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov - что там странного? Это пример взят из более полного кода https://github.com/BBGONE/TaskCoordinator там выполняется 200 000 итераций в секунду

Comment: @MaximT обычно возвращаемое этим методом значение кого-то интересует...

Comment: Павел, механизм действия yield одинаков, реализации и нюансы разные.

Comment: @NewView Нет. Аналог pthread_yield в .NET - [Thread.Yield](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.yield?view=netcore-2.0), а не TaskYield.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight А чем по семантике отличается освободить поток из пула потоков и поставить задачу в конец очереди в пуле потоков? Просто Task.Yield это делает в сфере TPL async await, а Thread.Yield это делает с потоками на уровне операционной системы. Однако, по смыслу они не отличаются. NewView писал про общую схему - какую функцию они выполняют.